# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" psql server version 9.3

Tags: postgresql

I am getting the password authentication failed.  I've tried with METHODS peer, trust, ident.  Made sure to restart or reload the conf.

```
sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres
```

Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

```
sudo service postgresql reload
```

My pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the config that corresponds to the DB that you're running?

Comment: Yes, because earlier when I was able to connect to the DB and I had found the config location by running postgres=# SHOW hba_file;
              hba_file               
-------------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)

In Centos 6  Linux 64

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I figured it out; somehow there is another config in the data directory outside 9.3 which is running now

Comment: @AdityaMittal: Where was the other config located? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @AdityaMittal: I can't edit my previous comment anymore, therefore I add a second one with additional questions and information: Did you mean that the database uses a different config file than stated by the path returned by "SHOW hba_file;"? In my case when I ask the database "SHOW hba_file;", then I get the path to the pg_hba.conf file also in a similar directory (/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf). I edited this file, but it didn't help. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @krm search your system for pg_hba.conf

find / -type f -name "pg_hba.conf"

Answer (score 0):

follow this step for ubuntu/linxs

-> sudo -u postgres psql

-> postgres=#

After that right

->postgres=# \password

Enter new password for user “postgres”:

Enter it again:

Now check, the new password is working successfully.